# WP_Query() and ordering items

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

I have to order items from wp_post by their menu_order (pages only).
I've written this line:

```
$query = new WP_Query();
$all = $query -> query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'DESC'));
$children = get_page_children($id, $all);
foreach ($children as $child) {
 if ($child -> ID == get_the_id()) {
      echo '<li class="active"><a href="' . get_permalink($child -> ID) . '">' . $id . $child -> post_title . '</a></li>';
```

I see the items but they are not ordered.

Thanks.
FZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the issue relates to the fact you are passing the `$all` object through `get_page_children` before using it in a loop.

Why don't you just forget get_page_children and add 'post_parent' to your list of WP_Query arguments?

```
$all = $query->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'post_parent' => $id, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'DESC'))
```

A helpful thread on Wordpress Stack Exchange;

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35123/wp-get-all-the-sub-pages-of-the-parent-using-wp-query

**EDIT.**

To expand on comments. Sometimes there's confusion about menu_order - it does not relate to  wp_nav_menus but to the Page Attributes Order input box, as shown below;

[image]

Comment: Daft question I know - you have actually ordered those child pages using the number input field in the Page Attributes dialogue box for each page?  I only ask because some folk think that `menu_order` relates to `wp_nav_menus`.

Comment: I think that the code interprets the menu_order as a string and not as a number ... just a guess.

Comment: Have updated answer to clarify. Just making sure the menu_order is all set properly!

Comment: Ok ... believe it or not ... it should be 'order_by'! That worked ;-)

Comment: Huh?  Really?  That's a new on on me.  Ah well, at least you got it fixed, well done!

Comment: My pleasure - Welcome to Stackoverflow by the way!

Comment: Excellent :) I was also looking at the incorrect place. Thanks.